# Tensorflow 1.0 on Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

I want to install Tensorflow version 1.0 on Anaconda.
I got the following error:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current cha
nnels:

- tensorflow==1.0

Current channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64

  Is this version still supported? How to install it?

Comment: install via `pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow=1.0` (or `tensorflow-gpu` if you want the CUDA-enabled version)

Comment: thanks. I got the following error message:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0 (from
versions: 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0,
 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0

Comment: Try downloading manually the appropriate wheel from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.0.0 Then just `pip install whatever-name-the-file-you-downloaded-has.whl`

Comment: I tried, but the only supported wheel for windows is for AMD which is not my platform (it did not work).

Comment: `amd64` only means that it's a 64-bit build. Tensorflow is only compatible with 64-bit systems

Comment: I have 64-bit, but got this error message:
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Which python version do you have? 1.0 only works on python 3.5 for Windows

Comment: You are right. I changed to 3.5 and it worked. A great tip. Thanks!